# How to run a chrome extension's content script on another extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So Í'm writing a chrome extension that allows the user to alias words—so by typing one thing, the extension can switch it off with another. This currently works great in most websites, including in gmail and gmail chat.

However, when adding the google hangouts extension (which takes over google's default hangout popups), my extension doesn't work. I have all_frames set to true in my manifest (so my extension's content script loads on all iframes and such). However, I don't register events or anything when someone types in google hangout's extension dialogue boxes.

Any ideas on how to fix this, is it possible to run my script also on the google hangouts extension, or is there another approach that works?

Here is my extension btw: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromedash/bbpiealmmbiefhppikadopbljoppcnoa

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you are saying you extension doesn't work, do you mean in current web page (contains hangouts) or hangouts's extension page (starts with chrome-extension://) ?

Comment: @HaibaraAi, with the hangouts extension enabled, any google chat window opened opens it with the extension. The chat windows are persistent, and don't leave when the chrome tabs change or are minimized.

Comment: The question asked in an earlier comment was specifically if the URL for the page you are wanting to run in started with `chrome-extension://`. While your response implied that was the case, what was really wanted was an explicit statement about the URL, not a generalization. So, *does the URL of where you are wanting to run your extension, but unable to do so, begin with `chrome-extension://`?*